# Python multiprocessing.connection Module Slowness

Tags: python, service, client-server, python-multiprocessing

To investigate on the slowness, I created a simple service. Here are some basic information about it:

- **Host**: Running on AWS EC2 Instance (Ubuntu)
- **Python Classes**: Uses <kbd>multiprocessing.connection.Client</kbd> and <kbd>multiprocessing.connection.Listener</kbd>
- **Service Function**: The service simply adds a period (.) to the input string and return it to the user. For instance: input string <kbd>Hello World</kbd>, output is <kbd>Hello World.</kbd>

---

***Slowness Issue***: the aforementioned simple service takes about **5.7s** for executing **100 requests**. Ideally I would like to decrease the execution time to **0.5s** for **100 requests**. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Below is the code for the service. Note that the code is consist of 2 parts: <kbd>server.py</kbd> and <kbd>client.py</kbd>

---

<kbd>server.py</kbd>

```
import os
import click

from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from multiprocessing import AuthenticationError

def add_emoji(words):
    
    words_emoji = words + "."
  
    return words_emoji

def test(port):

    listener = Listener(('localhost', port), authkey=b'test')
    running = True
    
    while running:
        while True:
            try:
                conn = listener.accept()
                break
            except AuthenticationError as err:
                print(err, flush=True)
        while True:
            msg = conn.recv()
            command, words = next(iter(msg.items()))
            
            if command == "words":
                reply = add_emoji(words)
                conn.send(reply)
            elif command == "close":
                conn.close()
                break
            elif command == 'exit':
                conn.close()
                running = False
                print("Closing the server")
                break
    
    listener.close()

@click.command()
@click.option("--port", type=int, required=True)

def main(port):
    test(port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  # pylint:disable=no-value-for-parameter
```

---

<kbd>client.py</kbd>

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import click

@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--port",
    type=int,
    required=True,
    help="Port to connect to the service",
)
@click.option(
    "--words",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="words passed to the server to run the service on",
)

def main(port, words):
    
    conn = Client(("localhost", port), authkey=b"test")
    conn.send({"words": words})
    print(conn.recv())

    conn.send({"close": None})
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() # pylint:disable=no-value-for-parameter
```